# Как реализовать step by step?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="calc_nav">
        <!-- before_active -  -->
        <!-- active - активний -->


        <span data-step="0" class="before_active"><em>Генотип</em></span>
        <span data-step="1" class="before_active"><em>Фиброз</em></span>
        <span data-step="2" class="active"><em>Интерферон</em></span>
        <span data-step="3" class=""><em>ВИЧ</em></span>
        <span data-step="4" class="result"><em>Результат</em></span>
      </div>

      <form role="form">
          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Генотип</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                      Генотип 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                      Генотип 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                      Генотип 3
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Фиброз</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Интерферон</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-4">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">ВИЧ</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-5">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Результат</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Отправить</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Вам на клиенте или бекенде?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets клиенте надо.....

Comment: @YuriyProkopets а как бить с calc_nav??

Answer (score 0):

Скрываем все панели кроме первой добавляя класс `hidden`. При нажатии на `Далее` текущую панель скрываем, а следующую показываем.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nextBtn').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var panel = self.closest('.panel');
    var next = panel.next();
    
    panel.addClass('hidden');
    next.removeClass('hidden');
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

      <form role="form">
          <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Генотип</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                      Генотип 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                      Генотип 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" required="required" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3" value="option3">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                      Генотип 3
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel hidden panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Фиброз</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel hidden panel-primary setup-content" id="step-3">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Интерферон</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel hidden panel-primary setup-content" id="step-4">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">ВИЧ</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn" type="button">Далее</button>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel hidden panel-primary setup-content" id="step-5">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Результат</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                      <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Отправить</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: а как бить с calc_nav???

Comment: Я не даю вам готового решения, а только демонстрирую как вообще такое можно делать. Потому как у меня нет целостной картины.  
`calc_nav` заменил на `container` только для того, чтобы применились стили bootstrap-а